# How can I make the dock's icons smaller?

Tags: settings, plank

The default options for the dock's icon size in System Settings are "normal" and "large". Is it possible to set the icon size to "small"?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You can hold <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> and scroll over the dock to change the icon size.

There is also a hidden preferences window for Plank. Hold <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> and right click on the dock to open a context menu, then select "Preferences".

You can also open Terminal and type in

`$ plank --preferences`

At the bottom of the window there is a slider to adjust the size of the icons.

Bear in mind, that elementary does not provide icons at arbitrary sizes, so your dock icons may appear blurry at some sizes.

Comment: Great answer, I wasn't even aware `Plank` had this hidden preferences panel.

Comment: Wow. "Ctrl + right Click" is a whole new level of working with Plank! :D Thanks for the reasonable comment regarding "Elementary Tweaks" though!

Comment: I just learned about it too! And you're welcome, it's a shame that tweaks isn't maintained or supported.

Answer (score 7):

A better method to configure very quickly is to Hover your mouse over plank and press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> and then scroll the mouse. Up increases the size and vice-versa.

This method does have a setback that you do not know what is the current size of the icons and you might get a little blurry icons.

Answer (score 5):

Open the configuration file of the dock:

```
scratch-text-editor ~/.config/plank/dock1/settings
```

Find the line `IconSize=48` and and replace `48` by `32` or any other number.